Resizeable/Draggable and Containment on 2 Divs Malfunctioning?
I'm trying to have two 2 separate Divs resizable, draggable and in the SAME containment Div.
This is what I have tried.


$(".main .box1").draggable({ containment: ".main" }).resizable({ containment: ".main" });
$(".main .box2").draggable({ containment: ".main" }).resizable({ containment: ".main" });
body {
    background-color: #6A6A6A;
    overflow: hidden;
}

html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}

.box {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

.main {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

.box1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: black;
}

.box2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    right: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: black;
}
<div class="main">
    <div class="box1"></div>
    <div class="box2"></div>
</div>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.14.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.14.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>



This only works on 1 Div. The other just disappears. In other ways, I tried the divs were always in sync.
So my question is How do you Have multiple Divs with the same Containment box?
